# Question about $(n^2+1)*(\dfrac{1}{n}+o(\dfrac{1}{n}))$

Tags: calculus, limits

In the limit $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \dfrac{ (n^2+1)\log(1+\dfrac{1}{n}) }{ n+n^x }$

Can you explain me why the product

$(n^2+1)*(\dfrac{1}{n}+o(\dfrac{1}{n}))$

is equal to $n$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just compute term by term to get
$$n + o(n) + 1/n + o(1/n).$$
Basically the last two terms go to 0, so they don’t interfere with the asymptotic behaviour. The term o(n) is the result of $n^2o(1/n)$ which is for sure something that asymptotically grows slower than n, whence you have the result that asymptotically all that expression behaves like $n$.

Answer (score 0):

$(n^2+1)*(\dfrac{1}{n}+o(\dfrac{1}{n}))= n+n^2o(\dfrac{1}{n})=n$

Answer (score 0):

It is not:
\begin{align*}
(n^2+1)\left(\frac{1}{n}+o_{n\to+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)&=n+\frac{1}{n}+o_{n\to+\infty}\left(n\right)+o_{n\to+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).
\end{align*}
The following equivalence thus holds
\begin{align*}
(n^2+1)\left(\frac{1}{n}+o_{n\to+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)&\underset{n\to+\infty}{\sim}n
\end{align*}
since
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n}(n^2+1)\left(\frac{1}{n}+o_{n\to+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)&=1+\frac{1}{n^2}+o_{n\to+\infty}\left(1\right)+o_{n\to+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}1.
\end{align*}
The equivalence is not an equality but rather an asymptotic behavior.